# Searching a large PostgreSQL table against a list of phrases using ILIKE

Tags: postgresql

What is the most efficient method for matching records between a large list of phrases against a title field in a large table?

Is there a better approach: for example looping through the phrases_table rows one at a time using a function that is run hourly?

---

Three tables: 
target_table = holds the output from function, one row for each matching record
source_table = the table being searched  (60M rows)
phrases_table = table with each record holding a phrase used in the search (2K rows)

insert into results_table (target_field1, target_field2, target_field3) 
select source_field1, source_field2, source_field3 from source_table  
join phrase_table on ( source_table.title  ILIKE '%'||phrase_table.term||'%' ) 
on conflict do nothing;

---

The attached function does work, however with the size of the table I suspect this query will take days or weeks to run on our server and may run out of memory over time.

Comment: 60M rows is **not** that big a table. Just run the select part and see how long it actually takes. In doing so you may want to run [Explain analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) and post the results if you need additional help. If so then also post table definition (ddl), including indexes and keys for all tables involved.